# run a stored procedure by fetching from a cursor row by row on SQL server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to run a stored procedure on SQL server 2008.

But, I can only fetch one row from the cursor. After that, the @@FETCH_STATUS is -1.

```
DECLARE @my_table TABLE
  (
     id int not null
  );

  INSERT INTO @my_table (id)
    SELECT DISTINCT a.id 
     FROM  table1 as a  
     WHERE a.value = 'abc' 
     ORDER BY a.id ASC    

  DECLARE t_input  CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT id 
    FROM  @my_table  

  DECLARE   @return_value  tinyint
  DECLARE @my_id  int

  OPEN  t_input  
  FETCH  NEXT  FROM  t_input  into @my_id  # only the first row is fetched successfully
  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN
    EXEC    @return_value  =  my_procudure
              @arg1 = @my_id,               
              @ar2 = 9

        SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
       FETCH NEXT FROM t_input  into  @my_id  # this is -1 !!!!!!!!!!
  END
```

So, it only run one iteration in the while loop.

my_procudure run well and has nothing to do with the cursor.

In debug mode, I saw that the loop ran only one time.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: And the @my_id is used for what? You're calling your proc with constant values, right? Or are the `6` and `9` supposed to be parameters?

Comment: @NickyvV, I hava changed it, a typo. thanks !

Comment: How many records are in @my_table?

Comment: Oh, and in your cursor declaration, you're SELECTing id, but there's no column called "id" in @my_table.

Comment: @Chris J. Breisch, I have changed it, but the same error ! thx !

Comment: But again, how many records are in @my_table?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're calling the stored procedure with the same values multiple times, and just assuming that it's invalidly exiting the cursor. Put "select 'I ran';" in my_procedure to see how many times it's actually running.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code, it looks like the cursor will run a number of times equal to

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.id)
FROM  table1 as a  
WHERE a.value = 'abc'
```

If this comes out to 1, then it's expected behavior. You'll need to look at the a.value in table1, and how you want it to affect this procedure.